# Truncate table and insert dataframe to SQL, ONLY IF dataframe can be successfully inserted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to truncate an SQL table, and then insert a pandas dataframe.  My issue is, sometimes I run into an edge case and the table will be truncated, but the dataframe will have a null value in a non-nullable field in the database ... This results in my table being truncated but no new data has been inserted.

**How can I truncate a table ONLY IF my dataframe is "insertable"?**

```py
sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sql_connection_string')
sql_engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text('TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.customers').execution_options(autocommit=True))
df.to_sql('customers', sql_engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I tried using `if_exists='replace'` instead of truncating but this drops the table and creates a new schema

Comment: In what kind of scenario does it ever make sense to truncate the customers table?

Comment: @SeanLange The business requirement is irrelevant to the question.  It doesn't necessarily have to be the `customers` table.  It can be any table

Comment: Seems like you should insert the data into a staging table first, and if that all succeeds, then truncate and migrate. Not unless you plan to validate all the data in the application (bad idea).